# Removing part of string retrieved from $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] in webform default value field

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to figure out if doing this is possible. I'm not very good at php so I'm trying to avoid having to create a module or something else to do this.

What I am trying to do is this:
In the default value field for a section in my webform, $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] to return the URL that the form is on, however, the entire URL is retrieved. (`/cms/?q=content/82245940-initial-services`) I want to cut out the non-identifying part of the URL so that I'm left with `82245940-initial-services`. Is there a way to code this into the default value field(1 line), or do I need to create special code to do this?

Something like this:
`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"-"http://example.com/cms/?q=content"]`

Comment: how are you linking to this form?

Comment: @monotribe Actually I have the form setup so that it only shows up on the pages that I want it to. I currently have it set up as a block that is configured to show up on pages whose URL has this: content/8*. The reason I did this was because the eight digit number starting with the number '8' is the work order for tasks that are created. And I need the form to be associated with only tasks, not projects, organizations or other content types in the Storm project management module. If there is a better way to do this, I am open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'r working with drupal you should use [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias();
$value = str_replace('content/', '', $path);
```

Comment: I guess I'm confused where I would put this code. If I put it directly into the Default Value field for a textfield, the php isn't evaluated and all I get is, "$path = drupal_get_path_alias();
$value = str_replace('content/', '', $path);". If I put it in a Markup Field, I still get the same thing. If you could tell me where I should be putting it, I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module to pre-fill a form based on the URL